# bash script is trying to execute a variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a very short Bash script, like this:

```
variable="3 things"
if $(echo $variable|grep "^[0-9]\{1,\}") #if $variable begins with [0-9]
then
    echo $(echo $variable|sed 's/ .*$//')
else
    echo "0"
fi
```

`$variable` will eventually be the output of a command which will be a string beginning with either a number or the word "No ". I want the script to return just the number or else the digit 0.

I'm getting the error, `script.bash: line 2: 3: command not found` and I don't understand why bash is trying to execute "3" as a command. Any insight would be appreciated (or suggestions on better ways to write this---I'm not good with bash script).

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, your regex is either more complex or less complex than it needs to be. Just plain `^[0-9]` will match every line that your `^[0-9]\{1,\}` will match. Maybe you want to limit matches to those where a space follows the digits? If so, try `^[0-9]\{1,\} ` (note the trailing space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
variable="3 things"
if echo "$variable" | grep "^[0-9]\{1,\}" >/dev/null 2>&1 #if $variable begins with [0-9]
then
    echo "$variable" | sed 's/ .*$//'
else
    echo "0"
fi
```

When using the `$(...)` notation, you are executing the inside command and placing it's output in it's place.  The directive `if` runs the output of that and sees if it is successful.  In this case, you really want to test the success of the command you put inside the `$(...)`.  It's also good to quote variables when used.

Comment: @penguin259: That works perfectly. I guess I got confused about how to use `if` vs `$(...)`, and testing return values (basically I was trying to test whether `grep` returned anything or not). Thanks!

Comment: @Wolf, in that case, use `grep -q ...`.

Comment: @Glenn I used redirection as that is more portable.  Some greps don't support -q or treat it as -s.

Comment: @Wolf Here's some more explanatin.  A pipe is a type of complex COMMAND combining mutliple simple COMMANDs in a pipeline.  When using multiple simple commands together in a pipe, the return status of the whole pipe is equal to the greatest return status of any individual simple command. Basically that means a pipe is only considered successful if every command was successful. The full syntax of `if` is `if COMMAND1; then COMMAND2; ...; elif  COMMAND3; then COMMAND4; ..; else COMMAND5; fi`  The `;` can be replaced by a newline. Basically, if COMMAND1 is successful, COMMAND2 is executed an so on

Comment: nice answer, but this would be more readable: if [[ "$variable" =~ ^[0-9]\{1,\} ]]

Comment: @Kim probably, but again, that is a bashism, the example I gave is just pure borne shell and therefore more portable.

Comment: I've been struggling with grep when bash has a `=~` operator?? Well, I feel silly now. No bash tutorial or reference I've ever seen has mentioned such a thing!

Comment: @Wolf I wouldn't feel silly, grep is an important command to learn.  I never use the =~ operator myself as it's often too unflexible for my needs.  For example, I often pipe multiple greps together possibly with some sed mixed in.

Comment: @penguin359: Oh, I know that intellectually. It's just that I'm much more familiar with the =~ operator thanks to Perl. Still, I probably won't use it; I'm trying to focus on learning bourne shell for scripting rather than bash since it's more universally available.

Answer (score 3):

Your script is not trying to execute your *variable*.
It is trying to execute the output from 'grep'...
The reason it is attempting to execute **3**, is for the same reason as when `if command` is encountered in the script.. The command's is run and its exit code is tested by `if`.. 
Your grep output presents `if 3` to bash.

`if command ;then do-something; fi`  is okay because `if` tests the exit code of `command`.
`if 3 ; then do-somethin; fi`  will fail, because `3` isn't a command...
Here is a simple example to indicate `if command...`

```
function error() { return 1 ; }
if error  ;then echo A-cond1 ; else echo A-cond2 ;fi
if echo -n;then echo B-cond1 ; else echo B-cond2 ;fi
# `if 3` fails as you already know..
# output:
A-cond2
B-cond1
```

You can easily avoid all that, and let 'sed' handle the condition tests and the output.

```
for var in \
  "3 things" \
  " 1 leading space" \
  "10 green bottles" \
  "albatross"
do 
  echo "$var" |sed -e "s/^\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/" \
                   -e "s/^[^0-9].*/0/"
done
```

Output:

```
3
0
10
0
```